# If the sets $A_k$ are measurable and disjoint then the simple function $s=\sum\limits_k \alpha_k\chi_{A_k}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

We define a simple function, 
$s=\sum_k \alpha_k\chi_{A_k}$
where the sets $A_k$ are all disjoint and the numbers $\alpha_k \in 
[-\infty,\infty]$

I am looking to prove that if we know that all the $A_k$ are measurable then s is measurable too .

My approach : Since by definition the simple function can attain almost countable values , arrange the $\alpha_k$ in ascending order. 
Correpondingly arrange the $A_k$ in such a way that $s^{-1}(x) = \alpha_k$ implies that $ x \in A_k$ 
Now for any t , we have that

1.) $t \in [-\infty,\alpha_1] $ or

2.)$t \in [\alpha_k,\alpha_{k+1}]$ or

3.) $t \in [\alpha_n,\infty] $

In case 1.) we get ${(x|s^{-1}(x) < t )}$ = $\phi$ which we know is measurable

In case 2.) we get ${(x|s^{-1}(x) < t )}$ = $\cup_{n=1}^{k}A_k$ since each $A_k$ is measurable then so is their finite union

IN case 3.) we get ${(x|s^{-1}(x) < t )}$ = $\cup_{n=1}^{n}A_k$ since $A_k$ is measurable so is their countable union

Hence these three cases together exhaust all the possibilities and prove that s is a measurable function.

Please check my proof and indicate if it is incorrect somewhere or if it could be improved in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct but you don't need to do separate case.

$f^{-1}(- \infty, t) = \bigcup_{i}A_{i}$ where $I$ is the set $k$ such that $\alpha_k < t$, and this set is mesurable in all case.